# Opera kiosk home page resets on guest account

Tags: macos, opera, kiosk, homepage, guest-account

I'm setting up a **kiosk** with **Opera** on a **MacOS** 10.5 (Leopard) and 10.6 (Snow Leopard). Using the Opera "[-kioskmode](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/)" on a *Guest Account*. The homepage at startup resets to "redir.opera.com/www.opera.com/firsturn/" every time i login again. I think this is because all application preferences are deleted at logout if the *Guest Account* is managed with *Parental Controls*. The Guest Account runs Opera at login using *Server Admin Tools' Workgroup Manager*.
**I need to set up my own home page.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be enough to just put the home page's URL in the command line? That way, it will always be opened when starting Opera.

It may also be possible to point `-personaldir` or `$OPERA_PERSONALDIR` to somewhere outside the auto-deleted locations.

Comment: I tried to put the home page's URL in the script that runs Opera in kioskmode. It works. The only problem is that in the Guest Account this makes two tabs. The first one is "Welcome to Opera". The second is my home page.

Comment: if the personal directory isn't erased between sessions it isn't really kiosk mode, is it?

Answer (score 0):

I knew I guy who used to customize portable versions of Opera for his own use. I don't know if it's possible on OSX too or not, but on Windows it definitely had the ability to have a fully customized, one session browser.

http://www.kejut.com/operaportable This one is a little outdated, and only for Windows. just to prove my point.

http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2011/01/21/opera-for-mac-now-available-as-a-portable-app/ This one might help you to set up portable Opera on OSX. Sorry, I can't try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running a sh script on every login that creates a opera preferences file with the needed home page. Determine what triggers the "fistrun" page by looking at everything in the personaldir.

To make this easy, extend upon grawity's solution and don't just set the personaldir somewhere else, no, COPY the personaldir from a permanent location everytime a session starts up!